# How to display latest sample value for a point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, date, feature-dataset

We have a dataset consisting of points (x,y). At each of these points, analytical data has been collected at different dates. The dates are not the same for all points. An example of the dataset is shown below:

Point; x; y; date; analytical data
B1; x1; y1; 1-1-17; 10
B1; x1; y1; 1-2-17; 100
B1; x1; y1; 1-3-17; 5
B2; x2; y2; 1-1-17; 1
B2; x2; y2; 1-3-17; 10
B2; x2; y2; 1-4-17; 100
B3; x3; y3; 1-2-17; 1000

The question is now: In QGIS, how can we plot the 'analytical data' from the *latest* sampling date? So, one value for each point.

We assume this can be done by using 'an expression', we just cannot figure out how?

Answer (score 2):

Could **Virtual Layer** be an option?

`SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, max(date) FROM your_layer GROUP BY Point)`

if `Point` field is not unique, then:

`SELECT * FROM ( SELECT *, max(date) FROM your_layer GROUP BY geometry)`

By the way, you might have to change the style of your `date` field to `2017-01-01`.